# Why is this Redux slice returning an initialization error?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, solana

Hey SO community I'm developing a dApp on Solana and I'm using Redux for state management. I'm creating a Redux slice that holds the state of the current "tip receiver" wallet address. I'm using Redux toolkit's `createSlice` but I keep getting this initialization error in my console:

```
redux.js:473 Uncaught Error: The slice reducer for key "receiver" returned undefined during initialization.
If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. 
The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.
    at redux.js:473:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at assertReducerShape (redux.js:466:1)
    at combineReducers (redux.js:531:1)
    at configureStore (configureStore.ts:147:1)
    at ./src/app/store.js (store.js:7:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/index.js (counterSlice.js:73:1)
```

This is my slice at `receiverAddressSlice.js`:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initalState = {
    value: '',
}

const receiverAddressSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'receiver',
    initalState,
    reducers: {
        selectReceiver(state, action) {
            const address = action.payload;
            state.value = address;
        }
    }
});

export const { selectReceiver } = receiverAddressSlice.actions;

export const selectWalletAddress = (state) => state.receiver.value;

export default receiverAddressSlice.reducer;
```

I've seen lots of answers here that say you need to add a default case but I'm not using the traditional switch statement. How can I `explicitly return the initial state` when using `createSlice`? I haven't been able to find anything about this in the official Redux documentation.

#### For reference

`store.js`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice';
import postingReducer from './Slices/postingSlice';
import tippingReducer from './Slices/tippingSlice';
import receiverReducer from './Slices/receiverAddressSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
    posting: postingReducer,
    tipping: tippingReducer,
    receiver: receiverReducer
  },
});
```

The part of `content.js` where I attempt to dispatch the action in the slice:

```
 {posts.filter(post => post.account.title != "BAYC #197" && post.account.cta != "https://twitter.com/dxlantxch").map((post, index) => (
                 <div className=" w-1/2 p-1 shadow-xl bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-500 via-red-500 to-yellow-500 rounded-3xl m-6">
                 <a className="block p-6 bg-white sm:p-8 rounded-3xl text-black flex" href="">
                    <div className="sm:pr-1">
                        <h1 className="text-2xl mb-3 font-bold">{post.account.title}</h1>
                        {/* <h1 className="text-9xl">️</h1> */}
                        <a href={post.account.artwork} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'>
                            <img  className="shadow-2xl rounded-sm h-auto max-w-full " src={post.account.artwork}>
                            </img>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-center m-2">
                        <h3 className="font-bold">Created by {shortenAddress(post.account.creator.toString())}</h3> 
                        <p className='my-2'>{post.account.description}</p>
                        <button className="w-1/3 border-black border-2 bg-black text-white rounded-lg p-2 my-4" 
                        onClick={(event) => {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            dispatch(toggle());
                            console.log(tipping);
//attempting to dispatch
                            dispatch(selectReceiver(post.account.creator.toString()));
                        }}
                        >
                           TIP
                        </button>
                        <div className="w-full flex justify-evenly pt-3 pl-2 my-4">
                            <div className="flex">
                              <div>  
                                 <BiUpvote className="text-xl"/>
                                 <BiDownvote className="text-xl"/>
                              </div>
                              <p className="text-gray-600 pt-1 pl-1">{post.account.points.toString()}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex">
                                 <FiStar className='text-4xl'/>
                                 <p className="text-gray-600 pt-1 pl-1">{post.account.stars.toString()}</p>
                            </div>
                            {post.account.cta ? 
                            <button className='border-black border-2 rounded-lg bg-black text-white w-1/4 p-1 hover:shadow-2xl hover:bg-gray-700 hover:border-gray-700'>
                                <a href={post.account.cta} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer">
                                    <span className="underline underline-offset-2">More?</span>
                                </a>
                            </button> :
                            <>

                            </>
}
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                 </a>   
               </div>
            ))}
```

Comment: **Just a typo**. `initalState` should be `initialState`

Comment: @AloisoJunior that's not how the redux toolkit guidelines say to do so. See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice

Comment: @Phil you are right!

Answer (score 0):

Correct the spelling from `initalState` to `initialState`, that could be the problem. Just had the same problem and had to scrambled around a little bit before I realized it.